A film where villagers are stoned to death
I can only remember a few scenes from this film but i hope someone can help me :)
It was an American movie and I saw it sometime between '80 and '95.
I remember a guy visiting a small village/town and staying at a bed & breakfast for a few nights. (I think he takes a liking to the owner's daughter.)
There is a part in the film where a woman is shackled and people stone her to death (I think there is some kind of 'lottery' where people are chosen to be sacrificed this way every so often, I cant remember).
This is all I can remember, sorry. I hope someone can help me.

Sounds like The Lottery from 1996, which was based on the famous short story where a woman is stoned to death each year in small town.

On his deathbed in the hospital, Jason's father asks that his ashes be spread over the top of his wife's grave. Jason, who came to the city with his father at a young age, remembers little of the town or his mother, but he undertakes the charge. It is an idyllic place, but gradually snips of memory return, until he remembers the significance of the fact that most of the tombstones in the town cemetery, including his mothers, bear the same day and month, one death each year. Caught up in the memory of the lottery he saw as a child, and the one he is trapped in today, escape is difficult and retribution is... 

Jason takes a shine to the innkeeper's daughter (Keri Russell). There was also a short film in 1969. The movie is currently on Youtube.


You did it again walt, ty  (have you downloaded the imdb site to your brain or something?)    :)

If only. ;) Glad you found it
